# I'm trying to pull data from the sql database, but the second part of the code after the case is not readable

Tags: python, postgresql, cursor, psycopg2

Error in python

[image]

Code running in DB

[image]

I'm trying to pull data from the sql database, but the second part of the code after the 'case' is not readable. But this one when in sql works, but does not work in Python. Help please

```
cursor.execute('SELECT  distinct created_date from analitics','case when cast("("created_date")") = cast(now() as DATE) then (Yes) else (No) end FROM analitics')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your python code is incorrect. Update it as below:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT  distinct created_date from analitics, case when cast(created_date) = cast(now() as DATE) then "Yes" else "No" end FROM analitics')
```